# Get list of users within individual geographical range

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geographic-distance

A list of users with their location (long & lat) and a radius (in kilometers) is given in my firebase database, effectively defining individual "action circles", e.g.

```
{
  "users": {
    "foo": {
      "lat": 11.2549387,
      "long": 17.3419559,
      "radius": 50
    },
    "bar": {
      "lat": 9.5123445,
      "long": 17.1221547,
      "radius": 80
    }
  }
}
```

My goal is now to query all users whose circle covers a specific location (again long & lat). Since the list of users can be very long it makes no sense to simply calculate the distance to the location for every single user each time.

I am aware of [GeoFire for JavaScript](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js), but this does not solve my problem completely because it is not suitable for calculations with a non-fixed radius.

The solution should be either client-side (JavaScript) or as a cloud function. Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Well GeoFire is the solution for you because it will optimize the query for you.

> I am aware of GeoFire for JavaScript, but this does not solve my
>   problem completely because it is not suitable for calculations with a
>   non-fixed radius.

It will work with the non-fixed radius you just need to update your query's radius and/or lat long with the new user and it will get the nearby users.

For Geofire you need an extra seprate node to store each user's geolocation object

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm afraid that doing this might lead to a pretty long response time for my end user (several hundred users in database). Or am I maybe overestimating the processing time?

Comment: It will be optimized, geofire will index data on geohash so instead of calculating distance it will use geohash to find nearest items. Do check out the benefits of using geohash.

Comment: So processing time will not be very long

Comment: That would still mean to update the criteria for GeoFire for every single user in the database each time I am making such a request, resulting in hundreds of queries. Am I missing something or are we maybe talking past each other?

Comment: You want to read a user node and then ask geofire i have this location and this radius show me other users in this radius right?

Comment: Almost. Imagine a map where every user is drawn into by means of a circle with their individual radius. I am now picking a point on that map and would like to get all users whose circle covers my point.

Comment: Well this is different you have all the users on the map already and you want to see which one are covering a certain point on map. It will be an expensive operation you have to check that point with other user currently visible on map

Comment: To optimize you can limit the user added to the map at one point

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option. Thanks anyways for your help!